# Android Studio 3.5.2 can't find USB connected device (but found through adb terminal)

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging, adb, device

The title pretty much says it all: I'm working on an Android Studio (3.5.2) project on my Windows 7 64-bit running laptop, I connect my Samsung J7 (2016) to the laptop through the original Samsung cable but Android Studio simply can't see the device. If I try to do the same on my desktop computer (same Android Studio version but on a Windows 10 64-bit OS) everything works just fine.

Here comes the funny thing: the "adb devices" command shows the device (and I'm 100% sure it's my smartphone since it's the only device connected). The Android Studio toolbar keeps showing "No devices" anyway.

I've spent 3 hours on this and couldn't find a solution. I already tried every suggested solution around the web (stackoverflow.com included), but I achieved nothing:

- Disabling/Enabling USB Debug function in the Developer Settings of my smartphone (including revoking USB debugging authorizations)
- Running Android Studio as admin (sometimes it solves strange stuff...)
- Trying to USB connect through PdaNet+
- Android Studio built-in troubleshooting service (re-scanning for devices actually makes me see my smartphone but it's treating it as if it can't be used as a debugging device; anyway the smartphone-computer connection is just fine: I can browse my files and all. Killing and restarting the ADB server does nothing)
- Tried connecting both as PTP and MTP
- Tried both the Google USB Drivers and the Windows Update drivers (those the computer gets when you first connect the device)

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: And is this happening for different devices, a non-Samsung device, and a different data cable (just making sure)?

Comment: Yes sir, just tried with a Samsung S6 and a Huawei P10 Lite, different cables, both on my desktop pc and on my laptop. Same issue: AS running on desktop encounters no issues, AS on laptop doesn't detect devices (but they get detected through adb devices).

Rebooted several times the laptop and restarted the application also; tried Invalidate cache/Restart too: nothing. Thanks to both of you :)

Comment: Reinstall Android Studio. Or try to clear your USB history with [USBDeview](https://usbdeview.br.softonic.com/), maybe it helps.

Comment: Reinstalled this afternoon, didn't solve the problem. I think I'll just report this as a bug and see.

Comment: It's happening on Pixel and Sony phones to. Tried using another Android Studio install on different PC but same version of Android Studio (3.5.2) and AS will not see the device..

Comment: I eventually gave up and tried AS (same version) for Xubuntu on that same laptop. Works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

if you use linux as your PC OS. may be try to install adb will help you..

> apt-get install adb

that's work for me.